# hbox/vbox and number of cells/items in monodeleop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, gtk2

I've been experimenting with a development platform and have been comparing glade using GTK3 to monodevelop using GTK2 with the integrated builder.

However, I can't find how to increase or decrease the number of cells in a HBOX / VBOX other than inserting after or before the current cell. The default option is 3 and for a couple of boxes, I only want two, yet I can't find a way to remove just one cell. Everything I'm trying is removing all the cells of that box.

The "General" properties of "Box Attribuites" in glade includes "number of items":
[image]

All the property options under monodevelop (there's nothing similar):
[image]

**Although I have provided an answer below, if someone can point out an easier way to use the GUI to modify the number of cells, I'll gladly accept your answer**

Comment: I feel like deleting this but I found the answer, I'll post shortly

Answer (score 1):

I tried to delete it from the GUI initially however my selection must have been off.

If you try to delete a panel/cell from the properties area, you lose the whole panel. Don't do it there:
[image]

If you make sure JUST the undesired cell is highlighted as in this example, then right click and select delete, that cell only will be removed:
[image]